# Geolocation tracking and Google Cloud Messaging working together

Tags: android, geolocation, google-cloud-messaging, power-management

Is there any way to upload the device location data to the cloud whenever a "push notification (think is gcm in Android)" arrives to the device? The user shouldn't have to press any buttons or do anything. I'm thinking about GCM because I need the app to run on the background (it doesn't matter if it needs some extra battery power).

If I can't upload the device location data on 'remote' demand via GCM and without any user interaction, then I would like to recieve ideas about how to reach my goal, for example, passive location tracking and something else. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You will need to write a Service, you can start it on boot. You can use "Google Maps for Android API" to request one time location data using LocationClient.getLastLocation() whenever you receive GCM message. And once you have the Lcoation, you can send Lat/Lng Coordinates back into your server.

You can also do reverse geocoding, geofencing and activity recognition with the API. Please be careful with users location data.

Here's where you can start:

- [Google Maps for Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)
- [Making Location Aware App](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)
- [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Thank you!!! Just one more question: with the first thing you suggested, the user wouldn't need to open the app, right? It's gonna be working with 0 user interaction and on the background.

Comment: Yes you are right. Also you will need to start a service with "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" and even if you user doesn't open your app, that process will always continue.

Comment: Can I recieve the GCM from the service itself? Sorry, I'm new to Android native programing.

Comment: I'm trying to do an app for the user with phonegap build and use the service to recieve gcm and publish the current location, is that possible? Is the service part of the app? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am not sure about it. There are good reasons why you should build native apps but, there are also cases where products like PhoneGap might be useful. I strongly recommend you to research comparison between native and HTML5 apps. There's a good talk about this from one Google IO session. Check that out.